# Django form doesn't render

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hello and thank you in advance.  I have a django form that is not rendering on a template.  The "submit" button renders, but the form doesn't. I have been staring at this code for about 6 hours and it is probably something very simple, I probably need another pair of eyes on it.

My Model:

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class DraftInput(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(help_text = 'Input Player ID Number', max_length = 5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.player_id

class DraftForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DraftInput
```

My views:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from simple.models import DraftInput
from simple.models import DraftForm

from django.template import RequestContext

#...    

def draft_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DraftForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = DraftForm()

    return render_to_response('simple/draft_input.html', {'form': form} )
```

My template:

```
#draft_input.html

#...

        <h1>Draft Input</h1>
        <h2>Draft</h2><br /><br />
            <form method="POST" action="">
            <table>{{ form }}</table>
            <input type="submit" value="Draft Player" />
        </form><br /><br />
#...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you view source to see what's shown?

Comment: I had this exact problem because I forgot to adapt my `urls.py` to use the new view. It further used the TemplateView I added there temporarily.

Answer (score 8):

Reading the answers thread, it seems you're still out of luck.

Try performing these commands in a django interactive shell (`python manage.py shell`). It's possible that an exception is thrown when you try to format the form. When an exception is thrown during the form generation in the template, you won't see much in the HTML; but a django shell usually unveils the culprit.

```
python manage.py shell

In [1]: from simple.models import DraftForm

In [2]: form = DraftForm()

In [3]: form.as_p()
```

You can either see the HTML generated here, or would catch an exception. This will tell you more about what you need to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `{{ form.as_table }}` or remove the `<table></table>` from around your form tag.

Comment: This didn't work...I was SO hopeful...I used `{{ form.as_table }}` and kept the `<table></table>` tags THANK YOU!!!

Comment: after trying your suggestions and reading the documentation, I STILL cant get my code to work.  do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is a sign to move to generics classes :) Just try **CreateView** class

In your views.py file:

```
class CreateDraftInputView(CreateView):
    model = DraftInput
    template_name = "test/draftinput_form.html"
    success_url = "/test/listdraft/"
```

Simple create template:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    <table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" />
    </table>
</form>
```

And **very** simple list of records in your urls.py:

```
, (r"^listdraft/$", ListView.as_view(model = DraftInput, template_name = "draftinput_list.html"))
```

Comment: Someone thinks that generic views are better than generic classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ form.as_p }}` for example. There are other shortcuts. You can also manually create the form. Have a look into the Django Docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs

Comment: I tired using the `{{ form.as_p  }}` no joy.  I am going to check out the docs you recommend now.  Thank you!

Comment: After reading the documentation, I STILL cant get my code to work.  do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You could install the django debug toolbar and check whether form is rendered into the context.

Answer (score 0):

Try "form.as_p" or "form.as_table" instead of just "form" in your html file.

**EDIT:** check out the documentation and use one of their examples as a model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

In your example, you define form parameters in your model, which may be incorrect. You want to leave form specific modifications, like help_text in the DraftForm class, now in the DraftInput model.

This is a simple issue, you should just replicate something from the docs and then work towards what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: after trying your suggestions and reading the documentation, I STILL cant get my code to work. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @dpbklyn added some more information in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Could not quickly find the root cause, but the fields in my form only show up when the variable declaration follows the conventional `module.Class` form. The issue might be somewhere in classloading order.

```
from simple import models

# ...
form = models.DraftForm()
```