# Form doesn't display in template - Django

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I try to create a form in Django's app but nothing display in browser.

Here my app.models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Scrape(models.Model):
  query = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date = models.DateTimeField('date scraped')
  h3 = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  links = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
  meta = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
```

Here my app.forms.py :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app.models import Scrape
    
class ScrapeForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Scrape
        fields = ['query',]
```

Here my app.views.py :

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms, template
from .forms import ScrapeForm

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    
    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'index'

    html_template = loader.get_template( 'index.html' )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    try:
        
        load_template      = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        context['segment'] = load_template
        
        html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except:
    
        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-500.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

def get_query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScrapeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('coucou')
            return redirect('/scraping')
    else:
        form = ScrapeForm()
    
    return render(request, "scraping.html", {'form': form})
```

Here my scraping.html :

```
<form class="navbar-search form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto post-form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
           <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
           </div>
         {{ form }}
                <input class="input-group-text" type="submit" value="OK" style="color:initial">
         </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

When I inspect html page, form doesn't exist.

I tried {{form.as_p}} but nothing happens.

I have a result when I try with manage.py shell

Could you help me please ?

Comment: You have to use `{{ form.as_p }}` check this post for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

Comment: I've tried with .as_p but nothing happens.

Comment: you have to add query field in `forms.py` too.

Comment: Yes. I did it. 
class ScrapForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Scrap
        fields = ['query',]
Bt it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What did you try in the shell?

Comment: Can you post the entire views.py file?

Comment: in shell, I try this :

[In 1] from app.forms import ScrapForm
[In 2] form = ScrapForm()
[In 3 ] form.as_p()

I've got in out :
Out[3]: '<p><label for="id_query">Query:</label> <input type="text" name="query" maxlength="100" required id="id_query"></p>'

For the entire views.py, I 've edited my original post for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove or comment this URL

```
re_path(r'^.*\.*', views.pages, name='pages'),
```

if you want to add custom 404 page than there are good examples are [available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725091/14457833) and after commenting it out you have to define a URL for your `get_query` like this

```
path('get_query/', views.get_query, name='get_query'),
```

and than you have to got to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_query/` this URL you will find your form

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Tiwari but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello @shamgroup try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17429589/14457833 and let me know if there is an exception

Comment: in shell, I try this : 
[In 1] from app.forms import ScrapForm
[In 2] form = ScrapForm()
[In 3 ] form.as_p()

I've got in out :
Out[3]: '<p><label for="id_query">Query:</label> <input type="text" name="query" maxlength="100" required id="id_query"></p>'

So, I think this form is created but it isn't displayed in template

Comment: as you can see your form have a field that you have defined in `forms.py` file so there may be a `css` or `javascript` is there which is hiding your form

Comment: or just try `{{form.query}}`

Comment: I've tried {{form.query}} without success and I don't find anything about CSS or JS

Comment: there maybe another issue you have your code on GitHub ?

Comment: https://github.com/ejulliard/SEO_project.git

Thanks for all !

Comment: Hello @shamgroup kindly add `.env` file in your `.gitignore` file or your all secret information is visible to all.

Comment: I've delete the key from .env

Thanks !

Comment: how you see you your `scrapping.html` which url

Comment: Hello @shamgroup check this https://imgur.com/o8OeMQY

Comment: I am able  to show your form what I have done I will post in my answer

Comment: Hello @shamgroup check I have edited my answer

Comment: Hello @shamgroup did my answer solved your problem?